# How to refresh hidden parameter default value in SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a parameter in SSRS reporting. Its getting refreshed when we make it visible however it doesn't get refreshed when we make it hidden.

**My concern is how to refresh the hidden parameter.**

Comment: When are you trying to refresh it?

Comment: i want to refresh it on other parameter (combo box) selection changed

Comment: I believe this is a known bug in SSRS.  The fix I have used in the past is similar to the one detailed here: https://bpmsbi.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/ssrs-cascading-parameters-refresh-solved/